# Achartengine moveable line chart

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

[image]i just create a new chart with achartengine and i notice that when i move the chart its going over the x and y axis. is there any way to prevent the chart to go over the x and y axis?

I also notice that is happens at the demo that come with the achartengine.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is now fixed in SVN. You can download a version including this fix [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: Hii Dan can you please answer to my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757166/how-to-make-space-between-bars-in-bargraph-using-achartengine-if-each-bar-is-dif Question.