# Bar chart not working in AchartEngine

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am trying to create `Bar Chart` using `AchartEngine` but various things doesn't work for me..

1) Unable to show Grid.

2) Unable to remove category series title i.e "Bar Graph".

3) It's not showing bars as it should show.

4) By Default white color background is visible.

is it possible to provide space between each bars??

**Bar Chart Code**

```
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Bar Graph");

    for (int i = 0; i < availCatList.size(); i++)
       series.add(availCatList.get(i), mTotal.get(i));

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());

        XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        seriesRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(0.5f);
        seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        seriesRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Bar Chart");
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Categories");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Amount");
        mRenderer.setScale(1.0f);

        for (int i = 0; i < availCatList.size(); i++) {

            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, availCatList.get(i));
        }

        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);

        view = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer,
                Type.DEFAULT);

        // layout.removeAllViews();

        layout.addView(view);
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `mRenderer.setShowGrid(true)` works fine in all the examples in the demo code. Try to set another color using `mRenderer.setGridColor(color);`
2. You mean the legend: `mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);`
3. `series.add(mTotal.get(i));` is the correct usage for bar charts.
4. That's probably from the profile. Just set your own background color.

Space between bars: read the APIs for `mRenderer.setBarSpacing();`

Comment: #3 its correct, but when i have only one data, it just sticks at the bottom.. Why background color is automatically changed to white??

Comment: if i have more than one data , its working perfectly now.. But if i have only one data, it doesn't looks good..

Comment: When you have only one item, call renderer.setBarWidth();

Comment: If i use renderer.setBarWidth(), then space between two bars has increased alot, is it possible to decrease it??

Comment: No, as I said, use the setBarWidth() only when you have one single item.

Comment: i also found one new issue, when data changes dynamically from 3 to 2, blank space is generated between 1st and 3rd bar.. Is this a bug in the new api?

Comment: can we make bars horizontally with new api??

Comment: is it possible to create different bar colors based on data that received dynamically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875769/how-to-remove-unnecessary-space-between-bars-in-achartengine