# How to remove unnecessary space between bars in AchartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

It just adds unnecessary space between each bars.. How i can reduce or remove it?? All data are dynamically generated.. I tried setting bar width but it doesn't work..

Please see the attached image..

***Updated Code***

```
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLUE);
        mRenderer.setScale(0.5f);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f);
        mRenderer.setBarWidth(75);
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(10);

        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);

        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 20, 0 });
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Categories");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Amount");

        for (int j = 0; j < availCatList.size(); j++) {

            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(j + 1, availCatList.get(j));
        }

        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Bar Chart");

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        for (int i = 0; i < availCatList.size(); i++) {

            XYSeries series = new XYSeries(availCatList.get(i));

            series.add(i + 1, mTotal.get(i));

            dataset.addSeries(series);

            XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

            seriesRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(0.5f);
            seriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            seriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(10.0f);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            Random r = new Random();
            int color = Color.argb(255, r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                    r.nextInt(256));

            seriesRenderer.setColor(color);

            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
        }

           view = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer,
                Type.DEFAULT);

          layout.addView(view);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated..

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: " I tried setting bar width but it doesn't work.." I have no idea what it doesn't work mean.

Comment: I mean even after setting bar width, unnecessary space still exists..

Comment: Set it to a bigger value.

Comment: why at x axis range has a gap of 0.5, i think that's the reason of issue.. Don't you think so?

Comment: setting the bar width to a bigger value, doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

When you only have one item per series, you could use `renderer.setBarWidth(width)`, where `value` could be something like `(screenWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) / seriesCount`.

Comment: @Dan
I have the same Issue for **Vertical** Bar chart.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636448/achartengine-android-horizontal-bar-chart-how-to-reduce-bar-spacing
Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

try Using :

```
mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.0f);
```