# how to remove spaces between bars?

Tags: android, achartengine

I have developed a bar chart using achartengine library.
Achartengine is rendering the blank values of the series and creating undesired spaces, how to remove that?
**Does anyone knows how to stop that??**
[image: In the image green , yellow and red colored bar showing the data on the basis of customisation , I have used mutiple series for one dataset, at jan , i have values of green bar only and blank values for yellow and red, achartengine was not supposed to render chart for them, but its still doing that..HOW TO STOP THAT???]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do:

- Use `renderer.setBarSpacing(0);`
- If the above only is not working then make sure none of the series has exactly one item. If this happens then just add an empty bar or one with `MathHelper.NULL_VALUE` as the value

Comment: I tried using MAthhelper.null values , in that case all my points sticks to bottom , i can show you the screenshot,

Comment: What version of ACE are you using?

Comment: I suggest you make the chart work with all series having 2 or more items and then get to this edge case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355225/achartengine-xymultipleseriesrenderer-renderes-chart-for-null-values-and-shows-u

Comment: Just update to 1.1.0. Get it here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/

Comment: I suggest you make the chart work with all series having 2 or more items and then get to this edge case.

Comment: I have done that only..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355225/achartengine-xymultipleseriesrenderer-renderes-chart-for-null-values-and-shows-u.. this is my code

Comment: :I tried it with the new version and without using Mathhelper class, its still giving the same result, I mean engine is still rendering blank values and creating undesired spacing??

Comment: Did you follow my suggestion above?

Comment: :I don't understand what impression you have, truns out you are passing such a comment...No hard feelings Thanks a lot for your time